# Why are there brown spots developing on my Coral Cactus?

Tags: identification, houseplants, diagnosis, cactus, discoloration

I have had my Coral Cactus for approx 4 years. Noticed brown spots developing on the fan part of cactus..never noticed this before. I am wondering what is the cause and what I can do to fix it
[image]

Comment: Good question; if could include an overall illustration & closer illustration of the discolorations, overall height, stem diameter, current watering amount & frequency, current nutrient amount & frequency, sunlight hours it receives, if some coarse gravel in the bottom and a hole in the bottom for good aereation & drainage, average daytime temperature, and average night time temperature, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help] to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

My research on the same problem shows that the original store potting, as in the photo, offers poor air circulation and drainage.  Remove from pot by removing glued stones on top and repot in a slightly larger, well draining pot using some sandy succulent soil.  Be careful not to over water.  Only needs water every 7-10 days in the spring summer and then sparingly.  Every two weeks in fall & winter.  I also applied some Neem Oil Spray that you can pick up at Home Depot or Amazon.  The Neem helps with any fungus that may have taken hold.  Spray plant and soak soil with it in place of watering every other watering for two months.  Recovery will be slow but don’t give up.